# Using href to set URL then reload. Working in Explorer but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some navigation links that set the URL and then trigger a page reload.

This is working as intended in Internet Exlporer, but not in Chrome.

In Chrome, when you click the link you can see it sets the new URL in the browser address bar, but then when it refreshes it resets to the old URL and loads the old page.  Here is the code:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MyAppController">
    <ul>
        <li><a ng-Click="pageReload()" ng-href="myApp#?appId=application1">Application 1</a></li>
        <li><a ng-Click="pageReload()" ng-href="myApp#?appId=application2">Application 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

```js
myApp.controller('MyAppController', ['$q', '$scope', '$location', function($q, $scope, $location) {
    $scope.appName = $location.search().appId;
    switch ($location.search().appId() {
        case "application1":
            $scope.appId = 1;
            break;
        case "application2":
            $scope.appId = 2;
            break;
    }

    $scope.pageReload = function(scope, elm, attr) {
        location.reload();
    }
}]);
```

Can anyone see why this is working in Explorer but not in Chrome?

Unfortunately, it does not generate any error messages.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Maybe it's not scoped right? I generally don't take chances with `location.reload()` and use the full `window.location.reload`

Comment: No, it does not generate any errors in the console in Chrome.  I get the same behavior with location.reload() and window.location.reload().  The page reloads, but it reloads with the original URL, not the one specified in the href tag on the link.

Comment: I recommend using a routing framework. It gives you much better control over your application and associated navigation.

Comment: When you need to change the URL and reload the page or navigate to a different page, use [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location). For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Page reload navigation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to determine why this does not work in Chrome.

I was able to resolve the issue like this:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MyAppController">
    <ul>
        <li><a ng-Click="pageReload('myApp#?appId=application1')">Application 1</a></li>
        <li><a ng-Click="pageReload('myApp#?appId=application2')">Application 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

```js
myApp.controller('MyAppController', ['$q', '$scope', '$location', function($q, $scope, $location) {
    $scope.appName = $location.search().appId;
    switch ($location.search().appId() {
        case "application1":
            $scope.appId = 1;
            break;
        case "application2":
            $scope.appId = 2;
            break;
    }

    $scope.pageReload = function(href) {
        location.href = href;
        location.reload();
    }
}]);
```